# Keyboard shortcut for show/hide the lower pane (Error List, Output, Watch) in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut or alternative way to show/hide the lower pane (Error List, Output, Watch etc. tabs) in Visual Studio. I am looking for something similar to `Ctrl + R` in Microsoft SQL Management Studio which toggles the Results pane.

I understand I can pin/unpin, resize or move around the lower pane but it is not very convenient. I like the fact that when I am typing code, Visual Studio on-the-fly shows the any coding errors, but for that I have to keep the Errors pane pinned, but that reduces my coding window, specially when working on single-monitor systems or on laptops. If I keep it unpinned, then I have to every now and then click on the Error List tab to check.

[image]

Comment: As an additional information: [Default keyboard shortcuts for frequently used commands in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-for-frequently-used-commands-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 5):

There is no command in **VS2017** for toggle the tool window. For me, I install the macro extension, write a script for hiding all tool windows and binds a shortcut key to this macro.

Here is the steps:

1) First, you will need to install the [Macros for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio)

2) Then in macro explorer, `Tools> Macro> Macro Explorer`, add this macro:

```
var windows = dte.Windows;    
for (var i = 1; i <= windows.Count; i++) {
    var window = windows.Item(i);

    // Check that this is a tool window and not a document
    if (window.Document == null && window.Visible) {
        window.Activate();
        dte.ExecuteCommand("Window.Hide");
    }
}
```

3) Set this macro as macro command 1 in macro explorer.

4) Finally, in `Tools> Options> Environment> Keyboard`, assign the 
   "Tool.MacroCommand1" to your favorite keyboard shortcut.

Peronsally, I configure <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd> for showing/ hiding tool windows

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>: Tool MacroCommand1 (for hide all tool window)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>: View Solution explorer
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>: View Bookmark
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>: View Find results
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>: View Output
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>: View Call heirarchy
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>: View Task List

Answer (score 2):

I haven't changed much from the default setup and on mine shortcuts currently exist for:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - display the *output*
  window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+-<kbd>\</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - display
  *Error* window

They don't toggle though as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, in Visual Studio 2019...

**Display or focus on a lower pane, if not already focused**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> ( Output Window, for instance )

Once any lower pane is focused, repeat the close sequence until all lower panes are closed.

**Close a lower pane**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>

This works with the default settings and no plugins are required.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Hot Windows](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotWindows) extension that provides additional commands for tool windows management.